# Parse.com .Net count query

Tags: .net, count, parse-platform

I would like to count the result of the query and I´m using the API Parse. The code:

```
 string appId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ParseApplicationID"].ToString();

 string dotNetId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ParseNetID"].ToString();

 ParseClient.Initialize(appId, dotNetId);

 var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Installation").WhereEqualTo("deviceType", "ios");
 var count = await query.CountAsync();
```

but the count is 0 and there is a lot of ios devices.

Is there any problem with my code?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Installation class is a special class, and as a string it is prefixed by an underscore, but there's a property for getting a query for it.

```
var query = ParseInstallation.Query;
```

You may not be able to do this without the master key, if you have public Find permissions turned off for the class (which you should.)

Comment: Fosco, I changed the class name  to "_Installation" and I get the error "Use the class-specific query properties for class _Installation
Param name: className", any idea?

Comment: ParseInstallation.GetQuery() require the classname argument. With the code: var query = ParseInstallation.GetQuery("_Installation").WhereEqualTo("deviceType", "ios"); get the same error ("Use the class-specific query..."). Could you see the image of Data Browser is the question edition? On mouse over of first Installation class I can see "_Installation" but I can´t get the count...

Comment: Sorry Fosco, int count = ParseInstallation.Query.WhereEqualTo("deviceType", "ios").CountAsync(); throw the error Cannot directly query the Installation class. Thanks

Comment: I was afraid of that, it's a good security feature....   move this logic to a cloud function, and call the function from the client.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54819/discussion-between-ernesto-rodriguez-and-fosco).